# How do I integrate the following function? $A=\int_0^1 x^{50}(2-x)^{50}\ dx$, $B=\int_0^1 x^{50}(1-x)^{50}\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$A=\int_0^1 x^{50}(2-x)^{50}\ dx$, $B=\int_0^1 x^{50}(1-x)^{50}\ dx$
then what is the relation b/w $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of Beta function?

Comment: no. I am an undergrad actually

Comment: ${\beta (x,y)=\int _{0}^{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt}$

Comment: So how do i solve his actually

Comment: Lemme write it.

Comment: Which book is this problem from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can obatin the relationship between $A$ and $B$ without explicitly computing both. Indeed, by the substitution $x \mapsto 2-x$, we get

$$ A = \int_{1}^{2} (2-x)^{50}x^{50} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Using this,

\begin{align*}
2A
&= \int_{0}^{1} (2-x)^{50}x^{50} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{1}^{2} (2-x)^{50}x^{50} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{2} (2-x)^{50}x^{50} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2^{101} \int_{0}^{1} (1-u)^{50}u^{50} \, \mathrm{d}u, \qquad \text{where } x = 2u.
\end{align*}

This shows that

$$A = 2^{100}B.$$

*Addendum.* To evaluate $B$, one may either invoke the beta function identity or show that

$$ I_{m,n} := \int_{0}^{1} x^{m}(1-x)^{n} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!} $$

holds for all non-negative integers $m, n$. This may be accomplished in several ways, including:

1. Show that $$I_{m+1,n-1} = \frac{m+1}{n} I_{m,n} $$ for all $m \geq 0$ and $n\geq 1$ using integration by parts. Then solve this recurrence relation.
2. Show that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} I_{k,n-k}\binom{n}{k} z^k = \int_{0}^{1} (1 - (1-z)x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1+z+\cdots+z^n}{1+n} $$ holds. Then compare the coefficient of $z^k$'s.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

We begin with the second one. $B=\int_0^1 x^{50}(1-x)^{50}\ dx.$ Using the following identity $${\beta (x,y)=\int _{0}^{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt}$$ we have that

$B= \beta(51,51).$ Also, we have the following relation $\beta (x,y)={\frac {\Gamma (x)\,\Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (x+y)}}.$ Therefore, $B= \beta(51,51) = {\frac {\Gamma (51)\,\Gamma (51)}{\Gamma (51+51)}}$.

Finally, $\Gamma (51) = 50!$ (In genereal, $\Gamma (n)= (n-1)!$ for any positive integer $n$.

Therefore, $B= \frac{50! 50!}{101!}.$

For A, please see Sangchul Lee's explanation.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: You're more than welcome. I am sorry I could not provide any answer that does not require beta and gamma functions.